# Use SharePoint Edit List Item form as Separate page

Tags: list, custom-form, list-form, application-pages, edit-form

I have a requirement to use SharePoint Edit List Item form as Separate page.
such that when i open this page it should be linked to specific item in the list.
For example by default it should fetch that item which has submit status 'yes'..
Is this possible.I am new to share point.. plss help(let me know if my query is not clear).
Thanks

Comment: If you are planning to build custom forms than kindly follow this...https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-custom-list-form-using-SharePoint-Designer-917d8fdb-ee00-4441-adb3-a94612d1d105

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the default for your List Settings is to open Forms as a Modal Dialog instead of a separate page.

Open your List settings ->  Advanced settings:

[image]